# Django sending unsubscribe link with email

Tags: django, python-3.x

how can i add an unsubscribe link in emails being sent. Also i want the user to be able to unsubscribe without being logged in. I am using Django==2.0.2. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You should consider using a token to bind an user to your database

Comment: could you please give me an example or some reference in the docs. @gogaz

Comment: take a look at [this](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-is-a-url-token)